# Unable to connect to the internet to check for updates in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I need to update an SVN plugin on JDeveloper, but the IDE update always return this error: unable to connect to the internet to check for updates

It opens a window to enter proxy information, but I don't use.

Comment: Are you sure your company computer isn't behind a proxy ? Ask your network administrator and if so set it up in the jdevelopper settings

Comment: I already checked with the network administrator, and there is no proxy